# How to create a shortcut to run a command and then exit?

Tags: shortcuts, cmd.exe

I was looking for something like this:

.bat or .exe file to run "ipconfig /renew" ONCE and then exit.

Im planning on making this an autorun cause windows wont identify the network on its own unless I run that command.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did all the work for me. Create a text file entitled: iprenew.bat and put the following in it:

> ipconfig /renew

That's it.

Comment: Yep, the problem I was having is that it wouldn't close the prompt after running the command. It would keep spamming infinitely. I renamed the file and it worked. I thought I had to add another line to make it exit but apparently no.